# SOLV for Narcissistic UVC

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, alphametic

This puzzle highlights some cyclic power Relations.

Please provide detailed reasoning of derivation of digits from various power relations given below:

$Given$:

$A$, $C$, $L$, $N$, $O$, $S$, $U$, $V$ are all distinct digits varying from 0 to 9.

$SOLV$, $UVC$, $LSU$, $VAN$ are concatenated Numbers.

1)    $S^L$ + $O^L$ + $L^L$ + $V^L$  = $UVC$

2) $U^L$ + $V^L$ + $C^L$  = $LSU$

3) $L^L$ + $S^L$ + $U^L$ = $VAN$

4) $V^L$ + $A^L$ + $N^L$ = $UVC$

Back to Step 2..Repeat and Rinse Cycle of nice Power Relations.

Comment: Don’t be scared of number of equations. Deductive logic and reasonable assumptions will get you to the right result. This is no more difficult than some of my previous ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the following values are consistent with the equations:

> A = 6, C = 7, L = 3, N = 0, O = 4, S = 5, U = 2, V = 1

My first discovery is that

> If L is 4 or greater, one of the remaining digits must be 6 or greater since there are eight of them total, and 6^4 exceeds 1000. Meanwhile, if L is 2 or less, this also does not work because of the second equation, where U^2+V^2+C^2 = 200 + SU. Assuming maximum values for U, V, and C, you would get 81+64+49 = 194, which is insufficient. Therefore, L must be equal to 3.

Working from Equations 1 and 4:

> S^3+O^3+3^3 = A^3+N^3, as both equations equal to UVC and the V^L's cancel out. I feel like there may have been a more elegant way to figure this out, but I recall that 3^3 + 4^3 + 5^3 = 6^3, so I believe S and O are 4 and 5 while A and N are 0 and 6.

This gives us:

> 216 + V^3 = UVC The remaining possibilities for V are 2, 1, 7, 8, and 9, however we can rule out the latter two from equation 2 as 8^3 exceeds 400 and therefore cannot sum to LSU. 7 does not work as you result with 559, therefore V would have to be both 5 and 7. 2 does not work as your result would be 224, and both C and S/O cannot be 4. Lastly V=1 gives you a result of 217, making U = 2, V = 1, and C = 7. So far we are consistent.

Now back to equation 2:

> We have 2^3 + 1^3 + 7^3 = LSU, resulting in LSU = 352, giving us L = 3 and U = 2, which is consistent, and S = 5, leaving O to equal 4. We are now left with A and N.

Finally with equation 3:

> 3^3 + 5^3 + 2^3 = VAN, resulting in VAN = 160. Once again confirming V = 1, as well as A = 6 and N = 0, consistent with our original hypothesis from Equations 1 and 4.

Comment: Excellent deductive reasoning leading to the right result..this is one of my favorite..most of the people are put off when they see bunch of equations